Is "an inner product space $E$ is not spanned by $R$" equivalent to "there exists $H\neq0\in E$ such that $\langle X,H\rangle=0,\forall X\in R$"?
I'm learning Lie groups and Lie algebras using GTM 222 (Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations, Brian C. Hall). I'm having trouble understanding Proposition 7.18(2) in the book:

The roots (denoted as $R$) span $\mathfrak{h}$ (where $\mathfrak{h}$ is the Cartan subalgebra of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$).

The proof of the proposition makes use of reductio:

suppose that the roots $R$ did not span $\mathfrak{h}$. Then there would exist a nonzero $H\in\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\left< \alpha, H\right>=0$ for all $\alpha\in R$...

The above statement seems to make sense at the very first sight: if $R$ did not span $\mathfrak{h}$, then there exists a "direction" in $\mathfrak{h}$ that is orthogonal to every element in $R$, i.e. a nonzero $H\in\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\left< \alpha, H\right>=0$ for all $\alpha\in R$.
However, the definition of "a set $R$ spans a vector space $\mathfrak{h}$" is not exactly the same: Let $R=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_n\}$ be a subset of a vector space $\mathfrak{h}$. The set is called a spanning set of $\mathfrak{h}$ if every vector in $\mathfrak{h}$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $R$. In such cases it is said that $R$ spans $\mathfrak{h}$.
So here are two statements of "$R$ not spanning $\mathfrak{h}$":
Statement 1: if $R$ does not span $\mathfrak{h}$, then there exists a nonzero $H\in\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\left< \alpha, H\right>=0$ for all $\alpha\in R$;
Statement 2: if $R$ does not span $\mathfrak{h}$, then there exists a nonzero $H\in\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\forall\  c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n\in \mathbb{C}$, $H \neq c_1\alpha_1+c_2\alpha_2+\cdots+c_n\alpha_n$.
Are these two statements equivalent to each other? If so, how to prove it?

This is true for finite-dimensional $E$ (as in your case) and is false in general.

Now I seem to have derived statement 1 from statement 2. If there exists a nonzero element $H$ that is orthogonal to every element in $R$, suppose it can be written in the form of $H=c_1\alpha_1+\cdots+c_n\alpha_n$, then $\left<H,H\right>=0$ implies that $H$ can only be zero. However, I am still grappling with statement 2 -> statement 1. If I can prove that every element in the inner product space can be expressed as $H=c_1\alpha_1+\cdots+c_n\alpha_n+H_0$, where $H_0$ is orthogonal to $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$, then the question will be settled. Any hints?

@OliverLewis Hint: applying Gram-Schmidt, we may assume $\alpha_i$ are orthogonal to each other and are normalized. Then let $c_i = \langle H, \alpha_i\rangle$.

As commented, one can find for every $H \in \mathfrak{h}$ a decomposition
$$H = H_0 + \sum c_i \alpha_i$$
where $H_0$ is orthogonal to the subspace spanned by the $\alpha_i$ which is $R$. $H_0$ is just simply the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $R$. Then in fact, we have that "statement 2 $\implies$ statement 1" since if we have an $H \in \mathfrak{h} \setminus \text{span}(R)$, then the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $R$ is nonzero, i.e. $H_0 \neq 0$. With that we get for all $\alpha \in R$:
$$\langle \alpha, H_0 \rangle = 0$$
what was to be shown.
